# what's wrong with this php email script?

Tags: php, email

This email script executes correctly but I never receive the email. what's wrong with it? It looks fine to me.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "dan@thenuttalls.co.uk";
    $email_subject = "KISS Contact Form Response";


    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['reason']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $updated = $_POST['updated']; // not required
    $reason = $_POST['reason'];
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = "/^[a-z0-9]+([_\\.-][a-z0-9]+)*@([a-z0-9]+([\.-][a-z0-9]+)*)+\\.[a-z]{2,}$/i";
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[a-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Reason for contact: ".clean_string($reason)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Stay Updated: ".clean_string($updated)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

header('location: index2.php?op=Thank You');

}
?>
```

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html

Comment: What happens if you don't suppress the errors (via `@mail`) and comment out the `header` line? (i.e.: Are any errors reported?) Also, have you checked the mail/message log on the server (if this is an option) and your junk mail folder?

Comment: yeah please provide the output errors, its probably an stmp server connection error

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your smtp is configured correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Your e-mail sending code is correct. Check your SMTP server settings in PHP.ini

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = localhost (write your SMPT server ip address)
smtp_port = 25
```

Or configure SMTP on your local computer to send e-mail.